# Retrofit 2: How to set individual timeouts on specific requests?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I have set a global timeout in my Retrofit adapter by doing

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.client(okHttpClient)
.build();
```

Great! But I would like to set an specific timeout for certain requests
E.g.

```
public interface MyAPI {

    @GET()
    Call<Void> notImportant (@Url String url);

    @GET
    Call<Void> veryImportant(@Url String url);
```

So `veryImportant` calls I would like a timeout of 35 seconds but `notImportant` the default

Is this possible?

My research has fallen flat.

I came across this however but not sure if it will work in Retrofit

https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#per-call-configuration

Thank you for reading.  Please help.

Answer (score 7):

You can do that by creating overloaded method of your retrofit object factory method. It's maybe look like this.

```
public class RestClient {

    public static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 20;

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
        okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, int timeout) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
        okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(APIConfig.BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }


}
```

if you want to call api with default timout, you can call it look like this.

```
MyAPI api = RestClient.createService(MyAPI.class);
api.notImportant();
```

And use the second one if you want to call api with authentication:

```
int timeout = 35;
MyAPI api2 = RestClient.createService(MYAPI.class, timeout);
api2.veryImportant();
```

Another solution is by creating different method with different OkHttpClient configuration instead of creating overloaded method. Hope this solution fix your problem.

Comment: There's much more elegant solutions. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47388973/3841420