# Retrofit first api takes time equal to readTimeout

Tags: android, retrofit

```
.connectTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
 .readTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
 .writeTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

For this configuration, retrofit takes approx 90 seconds for the first API.
This is not for specific API. I checked this is happening for every API.

Comment: Please, take a look at this post, may solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378787/retrofit-2-how-to-set-individual-timeouts-on-specific-requests

Comment: Thanks for the update. but this will not help. because extra time is due to retrofit object creation. https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1489